# blueimg jquery upload file control - cancel during upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp, cancellation

I use ASP.NET MVC and blueimg jquery upload file control for uploading file. Problem is when I click "Cancel" button during uploading. File is removed from client side, but continue uploading to server and eventually saved to storage and record to DB. How to send 'cancel' message to my server method to cancel saving file?

Comment: Using chrome or any browser open Development tools, choose network. you should see (XHR) (next to all). choose this. Now upload and cancel file. In status column, do you see (canceled) in Red??  -- like this -- http://s23.postimg.org/40i930317/Capture.jpg

Comment: Yes, I have cancelled http://magicscreenshot.blob.core.windows.net/screenshots/FT4wIJhzTUc.jpg , but controller method continues to execute. Any way to catch "cancel" in my method JsonManageFiles ?

Comment: all you need is to find the cancel buttons click function and send a cancel that way. let me check the js files from github and get back

Comment: i had a look around and cant find the cancel button action -- have a look in your scripts to see if you can spot it -- check the docs here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki for ASP.NET, maybe cancel int supportrted

Comment: ASP.NET version on wiki does not work at all :) I can find cancel button and add handler to 'click'. Problem is I can do second ajax call, to another server method, first called server method will continue to execute (uploading and adding record to db)...

Comment: not sure what ways there are to cancel a download on a server by code. There must be a download process which you could kill and then perform some house keeping but that will be depend if that process contains the file name, otherwise it might be hard to find the right process